# Same code and same compiler: compiled difference size

Tags: c++, compilation, objdump

I have an [HP-UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-UX) compiler environment. Yesterday, I compiled a dynamic library which had size as 4896088. Today, the same code's compiled size is 4936968. How do I find the difference in the source code?

Is there any command like “objdump” in HP-UX aCC?

Comment: Why do you care? There is objdump for hp-ux apparently, though.

Comment: All exactly the same compiler, compiler flags and source-code? That seems rather strange.

Comment: If the environment is not under your control, e.g. you are running your compiler from a network drive, or if the software on your system is updated remotely (because it is part of a managed network, say in a school, university, etc.), it is possible that your compiler got updated and some static library, or precompiled header has changed.

Comment: @lpapp when supporting software you have released previously, it is important to be able to recompile the exact software you released, so that you can add debugging to track down a client's problem.  If the executable size is different then it suggests you aren't actually testing with the same codebase which was showing the bug.  So you really want your compilation procedure to produce ideally identical binaries ; but at least, binaries where everything is at the same address.